# Ubuntu 12.04 and Chromium full screen issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, chromium, fullscreen

I'm currently running Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) on Ubuntu 12.04 with dual screens if I change to full screen I can't change back. If I drag the mouse to the top of the screen and left click I see small drop down. (See Figure 1)

[image]

When I click F11 the screen attempts to return to normal but then reverts with the same drop down message.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Extra Information:**

*The issue doesn't affect the other screen running a parallel instance of Chromium*

Comment: Can you try the same on Google Chrome and see if the behavior is the same?

Comment: Hi LnxSlck I don't currently have Google Chrome installed but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm just wondering if that isn't an issue with Chromium, as it's not a stable release, could be a problem.

Comment: Looks like the stable wins out! It's working fine in Chrome, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I installed Chrome as opposed to Chromium to solve this issue so I though I would share how I did it and close this question at the same time.

First head over to the Chrome download page [HERE](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) *See Figure 1* and click **Download Chrome**

[image]

Next choose the right package for your system in my case it was the

**64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)** *See Figure 2*

[image]

Then click **Accept and Install** to accept Google terms of services and start downloading. Once it has finished downloading click the .deb file and it will automatically open up your **Ubuntu Software Center** Next click **Install** from the right *See Figure 3* and type in your password when prompted.

[image]

When it has finished installing you will see a new colourful icon in you list of applications just drag it over to your favourites tool bar and you are ready to go. *See Figure 4*

[image: New Browser]

References:

[Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)

[Google Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once.

You have to delete the configuration directory of chromium. This config folder is generated when you start the program if not present.

```
cd ~/.config; rm -r chromium
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a best long-term fix, but if you just want to regain control over an existing window, I found a good tip [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/DgyoEKQpEgQ/ce14ZJkMlrYJ) (assumes you are running the "Mate" window manager with multiple displays).

The basic idea is that this problem seems to be some interaction with the "panels" and you can make the window behave by placing a panel on any edge of the second display.  There are a couple of ways to do this, but the simplest to explain is:

1. right click an existing panel on the other display
2. select "New Panel"
3. repeat steps 1-2 until a panel is added to the display in question
4. use F11 to un-fullscreen your window
5. delete any unwanted panels (right click, "Delete This Panel")

---

Additional commentary...

I have encountered this issue several times over the years (with widely different versions of Chromium).  There are numerous hits on internet searches, and most of the solutions come down to various different methods "deleting the configuration".  An unstated assumption seems to be that you will also find some brute-force means of killing the offending window, and that resetting the configuration will prevent this issue from occurring for new windows.  Another, assumption must be that you don't mind losing your configuration data (such as bookmarks).